# Adding external lib to android project

Tags: java, android

In logs it writes that the app doesn't see the external lib, but I added it by adding lib in the folder 'libs' and written in properties. Help me pls, who knows

Comment: yes, sorry for my English

Comment: What does "written in properties" mean? You do not need to adjust any properties files to use a JAR located in `libs/`. You might also consider posting the logs plus the source code that triggers the crash.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/10/changes-to-library-projects-in-android.html

Answer (score 1):

**Right click** on the **external jar file** in the you have in the **libs folder** and then select **Build Path -> Add to Build Path**.

Check [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/cyberycon/archive/2011/05/17/using-external-libraries-with-android.aspx) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: This has been out of date for a year or so.

Comment: Oh forgive me sir, I wasn't aware of it. The thing is that this works for me whenever I face any problem regarding referenced libraries.

Comment: Your approach does not put the JAR into the APK file, and will give the error the OP is seeing. This change was added to the R16 tools or so early last year.

Comment: Put the JAR in `libs/`, and you are done. Both Eclipse and command-line builds will automatically add the JAR to the compile-time class path, plus add the JAR's contents to the APK file.

Comment: In Eclipse, if you have the Android SDK correctly installed, I'd actually recommend to do a right-button click on the project, select Android Tools->Add Support Library... you can also select with right click the Project->Properties->Android. At the bottom of that screen you should see the Android libraries you're including and whether they are correctly linked.